# Picklist field is moving when using scroll bar LWC Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-datatable

1. Click on the pen
2. Choose value
3. Use scroll bar to go down
   The whole field with values is moving down, it is not on the row. How can I set it in CSS? or maybe HTML?

[image]

lWCDatatableWithPicklist.css

```
.cardSpinner{
    position: relative;;
}
```

lWCDatatableWithPicklist.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountDataController.fetchAccounts';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import Customer_Segment__c_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Customer_Segment__c';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
 
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', editable: true },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone', editable: true },
    {
        label: 'Type', fieldName: 'Customer_Segment__c', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: false, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' }, 
            value: { fieldName: 'Customer_Segment__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    }
]
 
export default class CustomDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    showSpinner = false;
    @track data = [];
    @track accountData;
    @track draftValues = [];
    lastSavedData = [];
    @track pickListOptions;
 
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
 
    //fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: Customer_Segment__c_FIELD
    })
 
    wirePickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
 
    //here I pass picklist option so that this wire method call after above method
    @wire(fetchAccounts, { pickList: '$pickListOptions' })
    accountData(result) {
        this.accountData = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));
 
            this.data.forEach(ele => {
                ele.pickListOptions = this.pickListOptions;
            })
 
            this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
 
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    };
 
    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
 
        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
            }
        });
 
        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
    }
 
    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });
 
        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }
 
    //listener handler to get the context and data
    //updates datatable
    picklistChanged(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let dataRecieved = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem = { Id: dataRecieved.context, Type: dataRecieved.value };
        console.log(updatedItem);
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
    }
 
    //handler to handle cell changes & update values in draft values
    handleCellChange(event) {
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
    }
 
    handleSave(event) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.saveDraftValues = this.draftValues;
 
        const recordInputs = this.saveDraftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });
 
        // Updateing the records using the UiRecordAPi
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.showToast('Success', 'Records Updated Successfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');
            this.draftValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.showToast('Error', 'An Error Occured!!', 'error', 'dismissable');
        }).finally(() => {
            this.draftValues = [];
            this.showSpinner = false;
        });
    }
 
    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }
 
    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
 
    // This function is used to refresh the table once data updated
    async refresh() {
        await refreshApex(this.accountData);
    }
}
```

lWCDatatableWithPicklist.html

```
<template>
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="slds-tabs_card">
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-page-header__row">
                <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                    <div class="slds-media">
                        <div class="slds-media__figure">
                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-opportunity">
                                 <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:recipe" alternative-text="recipe" title="recipe"></lightning-icon>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-media__body">
                            <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                                <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                    <h1>
                                        <span>PickList In LWC Inline Datatable Edit</span>
                                        <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Recently Viewed">TechDicer</span>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <br/>
    <!-- /header -->
 
    <!-- create folder card -->
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="PickList In LWC Inline Datatable Edit" icon-name="standard:folder" class="cardSpinner">
        <!-- loader -->
        <div if:true={showSpinner}>
            <lightning-spinner
                alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand">
            </lightning-spinner>
        </div>
        <!-----/loader-------->
        <div class="slds-var-p-around_small">
            <template if:true={data}>
                <c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={data} 
                    columns={columns} 
                    onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged} 
                    onvalueselect={handleSelection}
                    draft-values={draftValues} 
                    oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    oncancel={handleCancel}
                    hide-checkbox-column>
                </c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

picklistColumn.css

```
.picklist-section{
    margin-top: -1rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
    position: fixed !important;
    min-width: 10%;
    z-index: 99999999999999999999999999;
}
 
.picklist-section .slds-dropdown{
    position: fixed !important;
    max-height: 120px;
    max-width: fit-content;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

picklistColumn.html

```
<template>
    <div class="picklistSection" id="picklist">
        <div if:true={showPicklist} class="picklist-section">
            <lightning-combobox name="picklist" label={label} value={value} placeholder={placeholder} options={options} variant='label-hidden'
            onchange={handleChange} onblur={closePicklist} class="slds-popover slds-popover_edit slds-popover__body"  dropdown-alignment="auto"></lightning-combobox>
        </div>
        <div if:false={showPicklist} class="slds-table_edit_container slds-is-relative">
            <span class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-cell-edit">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title={value}>{value}</span>
                <button data-id={context} class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-cell-edit__button slds-m-left_x-small" tabindex="-1" title="Edit" name="tes"
                    onclick={handleClick} data-name="myButtonName" >
                    <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_hint slds-button__icon_lock slds-button__icon_small slds-button__icon_edit slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_xx-small"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.37.1#edit"></use>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Edit</span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

picklistColumn.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import LWCDatatablePicklist from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/LWCDatatablePicklist';
 
export default class PicklistColumn extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api placeholder;
    @api options;
    @api value;
    @api context;
    @track showPicklist = false;
 
    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, LWCDatatablePicklist),
        ]).then(() => { });
 
        this.template.querySelector("lightning-combobox")?.focus();
    }
 
    closePicklist() {
        this.showPicklist = false;
    }
 
    handleChange(event) {
        //show the selected value on UI
        this.value = event.detail.value;
 
        //fire event to send context and selected value to the data table
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('picklistchanged', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                data: { context: this.context, value: this.value }
            }
        }));
    }
 
    handleClick(event) {
        this.showPicklist = true;
    }
}
```

lWCCustomDatatableType.js

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import picklistColumn from './picklistColumn.html';
 
export default class LWCCustomDatatableType extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        picklistColumn: {
            template: picklistColumn,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context', 'variant','name']
        }
    };
}
```

picklistColumn.html in lWCCustomDatatableType

```
<template>
    <c-picklist-column label={typeAttributes.label} value={typeAttributes.value}
        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} options={typeAttributes.options} context={typeAttributes.context}>
    </c-picklist-column>
</template>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Hi @code234 sorry for that! :) the post is updated :)

Comment: Hi please check my blog post : @ApexNewbie
https://techdicer.com/picklist-in-lwc-datatable-inline-edit/

Comment: Change the style css position with absulate

Answer (score 0):

1. change the `position` on your `cardSpinner` class from `'relative'` to `'sticky'`.

   ```
   .cardSpinner{
       position: sticky;
   }
   ```
2. change order (class='cardSpinner' before the datatable) in .html -> add in `<div>` after comment `<!-----/loader-------->`.

   ```
    <!-- create folder card -->
        <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="PickList In LWC Inline Datatable Edit" icon-name="standard:folder">
            <!-- loader -->
            <div if:true={showSpinner}>
                <lightning-spinner
                    alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand">
                </lightning-spinner>
            </div>
            <!-----/loader-------->
            <div class="slds-var-p-around_small cardSpinner">
                <template if:true={data}>
                    <c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type
                        key-field="Id"
                        data={data} 
                        columns={columns} 
                        onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged} 
                        onvalueselect={handleSelection}
                        draft-values={draftValues} 
                        oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                        onsave={handleSave}
                        oncancel={handleCancel}
                        hide-checkbox-column>
                    </c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type>
                </template>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
   ```